# How to give permission to AnonymousUser to get room data using a passkey with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create an app with rooms that can only be created by an user, but anyone can "login" into a room with room Id and a passkey.

The thing is, I don't know how to approach this, I read something about overriding `AnonymousUser` but, since I'm using `simplejwt` to authenticate a `User`, I thought maybe it will be better to create json token with room id and passkey instead of username and password. Then let anyone with this token access the room...

But I dont know how to do it and I would like to get some points to what I should do or look up, since I haven't been able to find anything about it myself.

Comment: That's a very broad question, assuming you have no knowledge for Django and DRF I think you are better off learning and mastering a bit of Django with the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/ then think on how you would implement it without code, but as for now your question is too vague.

Comment: I'm just asking how to implement this, I believe if I know what to look up for I will learn how to do it, for now i do it as a post request with passkey in payload, that is not ideal, so im looking for a better way ....

Answer (score 0):

You can define a check permission method that validates tokens during the request cycle. There's a good explanation of permission [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)